# MAMP 4.x not working with PayPal Sandbox

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

Encountered another annoying problem with the upgrade to MAMP Pro for OS X, running Sierra and using PayPal payments.  There is a TLSCheck.php in the PHP SDK for PayPal.

When I run that I get:

```
FAILURE: SECURITY WARNING: TLSv1.2 is not supported on this system.
```

Please upgrade your curl to atleast 7.34.0.
    - Current Curl Version: 7.50.3
    - Current OpenSSL Version:OpenSSL/1.0.2j (Failed)

```
SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

I actually am using the latest curl and openssl.

I realize that there may be a number of issues related to that, but MAMP Pro 4.x is suppose to have the updated openssl and curl support.

My phpinfo shows:

openssl

```
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.2j 26 Sep 2016
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.2j 26 Sep 2016
Openssl default config  /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf
Directive   Local Value Master Value
openssl.cafile  no value    no value
openssl.capath  no value    no value
```

and:

curl

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.50.3
Age     3
Features
AsynchDNS   No
CharConv    No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   No
IDN     No
IPv6    Yes
krb4    No
Largefile   Yes
libz    Yes
NTLM    Yes
NTLMWB  Yes
SPNEGO  No
SSL     Yes
SSPI    No
TLS-SRP     Yes
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
SSL Version     OpenSSL/1.0.2j
ZLib Version    1.2.8
```

I actually recompiled the cURL.

I have a dev server and site (MAMP) running on my host with an SSL certificate and I can connect fine to that and the certificate shows up as valid.

Not sure how that all works, and I went through this once before with an earlier OS version and MAMP 3.x, but recompiling curl them seemed to fix the problem.  Do I have to specify the openssl.cafile path, curl_setopt($ch, use CURLOPT_CAINFO, /CAcerts/.crt");, or specify curl.cainfo=c:\path\to\cacert.pem somewhere, or is a paypal config issue.

Comment: does mamp ever work? i see questions on their forum from years ago that have gone unanswered.

Comment: It has been pretty good for me, but the latest upgrade really has some bugs.  Had to manually fix MySQL databases, the first releases were buggy, up to 4.06 now, and now this issue with PayPal even though they are suppose to and do have the latest openssl.  I think that there is some issue with cURL though.  I recompiled that according to another post, but still doesn't work.

Any suggestions for a different dev stack for Mac OS.  I could build with HomeBrew, but the MAMP control panel is pretty nice.

Their support is pretty lousy though.  No help with the MySQL issue.  I had to fix that.